Where to find Google Cloud security notification
I recently signed up on Google Cloud and started using a few Maps APIs. Today, I got this e-mail:
From: Google Cloud Platform <advisory-notifications-noreply@google.com>
Sent: Friday, June 28, 2024 18:14
Subject: New Advisory Notification

Dear Google Cloud customer,
You've received an important Google Cloud notification affecting your resource, lustrous-walker-427209-h5’s Google Cloud service(s).

Notification Title: [Security Alert]: Polyfill.io Issue for Google Maps Platform users

[Button:] View Notification Details 

Sincerely, 
The Google Cloud team 

I did not click on the button. I never heard of "lustrous-walker" and Googling it brought up nothing relevant. I Googled the notification title and got nothing with that title, but did see a lot of news about a "Polyfill.io" attack that has affected over 100,000 websites. I logged in to my Google Cloud account, clicked on "Console," saw the bell icon for notifications, and clicked on that. There were several notifications about my recent activity, but nothing about Polyfill.
I suspect that the e-mail is legitimate, but in case it's a spoof, I don't want to click on its button. If it is legitimate, I should have a notification somewhere in my Google Cloud portal about Polyfill. Where should I go to find that?

It seems to be real, there are now articles talking about this and was also covered here.

The email is clear a scam since it’s not your compute resource. The scammer is betting your familiar enough with the Polyfill.io exploit. If you have any doubts contact Google.

@Ramhound - Turns out the e-mail was legit. See the accepted answer and my comment under it.

@TommyZG - Depending on what you mean by "instance," you might be right. I found this "lust..." name in drop-down list immediately to right of "Google Cloud" heading at top-left of console. Opening that list gave me a list of projects, with name and ID for each. There are three projects listed, all default, since I didn't create any of them (at least, not on purpose). Strangely, two of them have the same name, "My First Project". The ID of the first one is "lustrous-walker-427209-h5". I wonder if it's a security problem that my question and these comments have broadcast that ID to the world.
